# Asus UX31E Windows 8.1 64 bit Card Reader Issue

Tags: windows-8.1, card-reader, zenbook

Card Reader (Realtech) of my zenbook does not work properly.

I've installed windows 7 64 bit's driver published by Asus for my device : not working

Realtek's own driver from its website (for win 8 64 bit): not working

Tried for another Zenbook which have officially published drivers for win 8.1 64 bit: not working

Tried uninstalling usb charger+ software of Asus (saw this as a solution on this forum) : not working

Please, would somebody help me?

I tried to ask them but neither Asus nor Realtek helped.

Ps. It works sometimes just after installing a different driver only once. On second try it stops working again.

Comment: What BIOS version are you currently using?

Comment: It is 214, the latest version.

Comment: It doesn't look like the laptop officially supports Windows 8.1. Anyway, what's the [hardware ID](http://bit.ly/1jbWdLD) of the card reader device?

Comment: You are right. It officially supports windows 8 but not 8.1. Hardware ID is USB\VID_0BDA&PID_0139\20100201396000000
And when i try to update its driver by using windows update it gives this error code: 28

Comment: Error code 28 means no driver was installed, i.e. it's missing. The driver package available in the [Realtek website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) does provide support  for your specific device and it's compatible with Windows 8.1 64-bit. What happens exactly when you try to install it? What did you mean by "not working"?

Comment: i don't know how, but when i download the driver that you linked, it started working. I still need to plug / unplug the card a few times, but it works eventually.

Comment: I have tried the driver on this link (seems the same, but it didn't work formerly) http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=15&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: That's weird; your link and mine are indeed the same. I wonder if there might be some hardware issues, because the card reader should work straight away, not just *eventually* :/

Answer (score 0):

If you go in to Device Manager, do you see any yellow triangle warnings?

Most laptops that have card readers are simply plugged straight in to USB socket pins, so, updating the drivers (or even the BIOS in some cases) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i've already checked that. When i uninstall the driver (anyone - because i've tried to install lots of them) the yellow warning appears. However, even a warning does not appear when a driver is installed, card reader still does not work. My bios is updated to the latest version, published.